# Trying to parse a list of values from a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of columns, the values of which I want to list in **1** new column along side the column name of the column.

For example:
flds = ['fld1', 'fld2'] # an array of column names

```
#ReportX would be the name of the column I want to push the value to.
#I want to create a column name and column value pair separated by a colon ':' - name:value
#I want each column:name pair to be separated by a bar '|' - name1:value1|name2:value2
```

So given a dataframe that might look like this:

```
       fld1     fld2      ...  fld10
1      234      'kjd'     ...  'abc'
2      45435    'ksjk'    ...  'def'
3      4623     'tdha'    ...  'ghi'
```

I'd end up getting a dataframe that looks like this

```
       fld1     fld2      ...  fld10      ReportX
1      234      'kjd'     ...  'abc'    'fld1: 234 | fld2: kjd' 
2      45435    'ksjk'    ...  'def'    'fld1: 45435 | fld2: ksjk' 
3      4623     'tdha'    ...  'ghi'    'fld1: 4623 | fld2: tdha'
```

where ReportX is a new column populated by the concatenated column names and values.

I tried using the map function, but that failed.

```
reportDF[ReportX] = map(lambda fld: fld + ': ' + reportDF[fld] + ' | ', flds )
```

It was returning a map object. When I made it into a list, that failed when trying to view the results.

How can I push the field names, and values into a column without knowing the size or names of the columns beforehand?

Comment: It would help to show the literals for the items in your list. Is `'fld1: 234 | fld2: kjd'` the value you're trying to write?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.name + ': ' + x.astype(str)) \
      .apply(lambda x: ' | '.join(x), axis=1)

0       fld1: 234 | fld2: kjd
1    fld1: 45435 | fld2: ksjk
2     fld1: 4623 | fld2: tdha
dtype: object
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure how or if the array of column names fits into this solution? Ideally, I'm using an array of strings (using the example above: ['fld1', 'fld2' ) representing the column names. What does 'name' represent?

Comment: `x.name` represent the column name of the series.

Comment: Did you have time to test the solution? Is this the expected result?